# How do you secure django hidden input FORM from malicious intent?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Lets say I have the following form rendered in a template :

```py
# Form
class CandidatTourForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidat
        fields = [
            "email", #charField
            "first_name", #charField
            "last_name", #charField
            "dossier", #foreignKey
        ]

# parent Model
class Candidat(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    dossier = models.ForeignKey(Dossier, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It is a classical form, nothing fancy. the `dossier` field is a hidden input.

```py
def candidat_form_tour(request, dossier_uuid, candidat_id):
    dossier = get_object_or_404(Dossier, uuid=dossier_uuid)
    candidat = get_object_or_404(Candidat, id=candidat_id, dossier__uuid=dossier_uuid)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = CandidatTourForm(instance=candidat,)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = CandidatTourForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and assertDataIsLegit(form._meta.model): # see below
            candidat = form.save()
            return redirect(
                "main:document_tour", dossier_uuid=dossier_uuid, candidat_id=candidat_id
            )
    return render(
        request,
        "candidature/candidat_form_tour.html",
        {
            "form": form,
            "candidat": candidat,
            "dossier_uuid": dossier_uuid,
        },
    )
```

When I test this view with POSTMAN and put a dossier_id that has nothing to do with the one received in the form on the GET request, the candidat is saved to the a wrong dossier.

I though about creating a helper function like so

```
def assertDataIsLegit(_object, _id, _id2):
    _type = type(_object)
    instance = _type.objects.get(id=_id)
    return instance.id == _id2
```

and calling it to verify that the dossier id sent back by the post request match the original dossier:

```
if form.is_valid() and assertDataIsLegit(form._meta.model, dossier.id, form.cleaned_data['dossier']):
   #do stuff save and all
```

But I'm pretty sure a better method exists.
I've looked into the form's `clean` method, but since I need to verify related data im not sure it is the good way.

How would you prevent this ? I know you are not supposed to trust the data sent and verify it.
Would you verify it in the view function ? In a form method ?
Any lead is welcomed !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be a question about computer and internet security (netsec), not a question about programming. Try https://security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I disagree, its totally about programming. Im loking for a way to validate the data received smartly. its django and python related. I know how I could do it (ugly way in the functions, for each django views), but Im looking for smarter alternatives. Using forms method or anyhting else.